# Android - Retrieve the photo of a contact

Tags: android, facebook, android-contacts

I am currently working on an Android application for the API 7+. In this application, the user has to choose a contact from his phone. To do that, I am displaying his contact list (photo + name) into the app.

I can retrieve the contact list and the photos without any problem and if the user do not have photo, I can display a default one.

The only issue I have is when the photo of a contact is sync with Facebook. In fact, my app cannot retrieve the photo and consider that the contact does not have any photo.

Here the code I use :

```
public static final InputStream getContactPhoto(WeakReference<Activity> activity, long contactId)
{
  final Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
  final Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
  final Cursor cursor = activity.get().getContentResolver().query(photoUri, new String[] { Contacts.Photo.DATA15 }, null, null, null);

  if (cursor == null)
  {
    return null;
  }

  try
  {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst() == true)
    {
      final byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);

      if (data != null)
      {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
      }
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    cursor.close();
  }

  return null;
}
```

Where should I ask for the photo to retrieve one wherever the photo is from (Contact app, Facabook, Google+, etc.) ?

Thank you in advance for your answers and your tips about the subject !

Comment: on a side note, you should be using `PHOTO` instead of `DATA15`. That's the same thing, only clearer.

Comment: @njzk2 : I know that is the same thing but the constant `PHOTO` is available since API 11 and my application is for API 7+. It is why I use `DATA15` instead.

Comment: true. but then shouldn't it not work on api 7-10? shouldn't you use `openContactPhotoInputStream` instead? (the api5+ one, not the 14+)